# Nodejs config which is subject to change

Tags: node.js, express

I was wondering what the best way is to save config values in nodejs/express which are subject to change. I'm not talking about database credentials that you store inside your environment variables. But say a game where the config values are changeable within the admin panel. A config for example could be how often in ms a player receives a random reward. I could store this directly into the code (but I'd have to alter my code everytime I would like to change this and this cant be changed from within an admin panel), have some different file that has an object with these configs or save it into a mysql database (I would need to query the db everytime I need a config though).

I'm not really sure what the best way is to do this. Basically I want a way to store flexible configs within my nodejs application that are subject to change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd store it in a database (or a JSON file if there is no database) but cache the value so I don't have to query it _every_ time. If you have only a single instance, you can just cache it forever and clear the cache only when the value is changed, otherwise you can cache it for a short time like 10 seconds which is still a great compromise between delay in changes taking effect and database query frequency.

Comment: @CherryDT I was also thinking about this indeed. How would this work out in nodejs? Would I have a seperate module and then a set time out running every x seconds to query the database and change the values? Or is there an easier way? I could also query the db on startup of the app and only query again when values get changed in the admin panel for example. What do you think? How would you tackle this?